# htaccess allow all user agents

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, curl

Since a week I cant access files in a WordPress sub-folder through a php curl function. Interestingly it works when accessing the file with a browser. When adding a 'fake' user agent header it works with the php curl function too. But I need other users to be able to retrieve the file without this hack.

I believe a WordPress update made those sub-folders more secure by restricting access to only valid user agents (Browsers). Also I believe that a specific htaccess configuration for this sub-folder will open it up again for all user agents, but I have no idea how to write such a htaccess config.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks
Aleks

Comment: Why is adding user agent to curl a problem exactly. Doesn't look like hack to me.

Comment: Which folder are you trying to access?

Comment: It is a sub folder I've created where I store a Google product feed. I call it a hack because even Google can't access the file and I can't tell Google to add a user agent. I need Google and other publishers to be able to access the file without the user agent header.